Failure to correctly implement ftp_nlist in php
I use the ftp_nlist command to check if the folder doesn't exist, then create it with the ftp_mkdir command.
But the problem that is there and has recently been created for me is that sometimes ftp_nlist returns a false value, which causes the ftp_mkdir command to encounter an error.
And what is more surprising is that in the next attempt, sometimes the ftp_nlist command that I try returns the existing array, which is correct and expected.
This problem happened to me recently and it was not a problem before.
Please guide me if anyone knows. thanks
if(!ftp_nlist($ftp_conn , 'public_html/images')) {
    ftp_mkdir($ftp_conn, 'public_html/images');
}


The problem here is that ftp_nlist() can return false due to many reasons, not only because the directory doesn't exist.
I think it would be better to use ftp_chdir(). If it is successful you know the directory exist and you can use it. If it fails you can make the directory with ftp_mkdir() and retry the ftp_chdir() again until you succeed.
It might be wise to exit this loop after a number of tries and report an error.
In code that could look something like this:
$counter = 0;
while (!ftp_chdir($ftp_conn, 'public_html/images')) {
    $counter++;
    if ($counter > 3) {
        break; // we failed, perhaps we should do more than just "break"?
    }
    ftp_mkdir($ftp_conn, 'public_html/images');
}

You could create your own function for this:
function gotoFtpDir(string $directory): bool
{
    $counter = 0;
    while (!ftp_chdir($ftp_conn, $directory)) {
        $counter++;
        if ($counter > 3) {
            return false;
        }
        ftp_mkdir($ftp_conn, $directory);
    }
    return true;
}

This function will go to the given directory, create it when it doesn't exist, and it will return true on success and false on failure.
I do think that the standard PHP FTP client is limited in its capabilities. There are lots of PHP FTP client libraries on the internet, there might be a better one out there.

When I use ftp_chdir($ftp_conn, $directory), if the folder exists, it returns true, but if the folder does not exist, it does not return false and gives an error.
